# Python Class gives different Output for @property Executed Each Time

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators, python-class

So I was using a Python Class with `@property` decorators, but each time I run the object instance of it gives different output.

```py
import random
generateID = lambda : random.randint(0, 99)
```

With the above function, I have created the two-class as follows:

```py
class A:
    name = generateID()

obj = A()
for _ in range(3):
    print(obj.name)

>> 79
>> 79
>> 79

class B:
    @property
    def name(self):
        return generateID()
    
obj = B()
for _ in range(3):
    print(obj.name)

>> 32
>> 94
>> 45
```

Even when I use `random.seed` I still get a different result each time. Is this the expected behavior? I don't understand. Please explain!

Comment: You told it to return a random integer. It's returning a random integer. Did you expect it to save the first value somewhere?

Comment: When an object is created, it should initialize with a random integer, and it should remain constant from that point onwards right? Like in `A.name` but for `B.name` it is different when I run the same object.

Comment: "When an object is created, it should initialize with a random integer" - that's not what `property` means. If you want something to happen on object initialization, put it in `__init__`.

Comment: `property` code happens on attribute access.

Answer (score 0):

so previously I'd encountered the above problem without knowing the full extent of `python-decorators`. So, if anyone else is stuck like me, then you can check this tutorial on YouTube - "[Python OOP Tutorial 6: Property Decorators - Getters, Setters, and Deleters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCzT9XFZ5bw&ab_channel=CoreySchafer)", by Corey Schafer.